# How to define spark submit configuration correctly?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I run my spark program on 6 PCs (1 master and 5 workers) connected by LAN. Each of them is equipped with 6 CPU cores and 8GB RAM. Below is my spark submit configuration. Based on my configuration, I have 5 partitions and I hope that each executor will take 1 partition and be executed in one different worker node so that all worker nodes is busy. But, when I run the program, 1 worker PC has 100% CPU and memory utilization, 2 PCs have 25% utilization and 2 PC has 0% utilization means it is idle (I investigated using task manager). The output is correct but I hope faster running time. So, whats wrong with my spark submit configuration? How can I define all configuration so that everything is distributed equally with no idle PCs?
I use this link for my reference : https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/part-3-efficient-executor-configuration-for-apache-spark-b4602929262

```
spark-submit --class MainApp --master spark://192.168.6.229:7077 --deploy-mode client --num-executors 5 --executor-memory 6g  --executor-cores 6 --driver-memory 6g --conf “spark.driver.memoryOverhead=6g” --conf "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=128m" C:\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\a.jar C:\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\Dataset\b.txt 0.1 5
```

Comment: from the setup you have it looks like you'd get the best performance by not using spark at all. this is a very small setup and the overhead of network communication serialization and coordination is rather large.

Comment: what should I do? please tell me @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz

Comment: what are you trying to do :) ?

Comment: I want all my worker nodes working efficiently. For example, I have 5 worker nodes. I want each node has 1 executor and each executor handle 1 partition. So, 5 worker nodes, 5 executors, 5 partitions. Or maybe you can tell me the best configuration for it. I just want my program well distributed. @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz

Comment: I got that from the question - what is your code doing

Comment: You can click this link https://github.com/nrthyrk/phui-miner/blob/master/src/main/scala/im/yanchen/pupgrowth/App.scala. Just focus on main method. I am trying to do the same thing but for different algorithm. But the flow is similar. @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my investigation, this problem was because of unbalanced job distribution. That's why some PCs are idle while the others were still busy. It is necessary to design good algorithm to distribute the jobs equally in Spark.